# this._best() is not a function typeerror

Tags: jquery, image, svg, onload, event-listener

I am trying to call a function this._best() once an image is successfully loaded but i receive typererrors. this._best() is a function because i use it in many different places and it is working. as soon as i put it inside the onload event in javascript it shows either typeError or referenceError.

I want to get the image height and width once the image is actually loaded and then call the _best() function after i get these 2 values.

I have tried many methods including:

```
this.svg.onload = function() {
            this.svg.addEventListener('load', function() { 
                this._W = jQuery(".Image").width();
                this._H = jQuery(".Image").height();
                this._best();
            });
}.bind(this);
```

and

```
this.svg.addEventListener('load', function() {
                this._W = jQuery(".Image").width();
                this._H = jQuery(".Image").height();
                this._best();
            });
```

I set breakpoints to see where it was breaking and it always shows error on the call to _best()

i also tried to test with an alert:

```
this.svg.onload = function() {
            this.svg.addEventListener('load', function() { alert('loaded');    });
            this._W = jQuery(".Image").width();
            this._H = jQuery(".Image").height();
            this._best();
        }.bind(this);
```

this successfuly calls _best(); and displays the alert once the image is loaded successfuly. but i still want to only get the values of width and height and call _best() once the image is loaded.

In this case i get incorrect values for width and height when the image is loaded the first time because chrome hasnt loaded the image properly but if i load it again it gets the values from the cache and it appears to work hence why i want to get the width and height from and onload event.

in the init function i have: 
     this.canvas = document.createElement("div");

my function:

```
        this.svg = document.createElement("object");
        this.svg.setAttribute("type","image/svg+xml");
        this.svg.setAttribute("data",url);
        this.svg.setAttribute("class", "Image");
        this.canvas.appendChild(this.svg);

        this.svg.onload = function() {
             this.svg.addEventListener('load', function() { 
                this._W = jQuery(".Image").width();
                this._H = jQuery(".Image").height();
             }.bind(this);
        this._best();
        }.bind(this);
```

and the _best() function looks something like:

```
    function _best() {
      var a = this.canvas.clientWidth / this._W;
      var b = this.canvas.clientHeight / this._H;
    }
```

the best fit is used to center the image. i use this function in othercases so this works but in this case when i load the 1st time the _H and _W are different to when i load it the second time. I guess chrome doesnt actually fully load the image until i click load image the second time.

How can i get the _W and _H when the image is loaded (just like the second load values i get) and how can i call _best() once these 2 values are retrieved onload?

Comment: There's no way to answer this, without knowing what `this` is, where `_best()` is, and how the functions are called.

Comment: i have edited the post. please refer to the new code now :) any advice? @adeneo

Answer (score 1):

you also need to `bind(this)` to your `addEventListener` as it creates yet another closure.

So

```
this.svg = document.createElement("object");
this.svg.setAttribute("type","image/svg+xml");
this.svg.setAttribute("data",url);
this.svg.setAttribute("class", "SVGImage");
this.canvas.appendChild(this.svg);

this.svg.onload = function() {
    this._W = jQuery(".SVGImage").width();
    this._H = jQuery(".SVGImage").height();
    this._best();
}.bind(this);
```

And I would also define `_best` as

```
this._best = function () {
  var a = this.canvas.clientWidth / this._W;
  var b = this.canvas.clientHeight / this._H;
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: i have edited the post. please refer to the new code now :) any advice? @mani

Comment: couple of things, firstly there's no need to have `this.svg.onload` and `this.svg.addEventListener('load')`. secondly, is the class supposed to be `.Image` or `.SVGImage` - I believe your classes don't match. Updated answer to reflect both.

Comment: that was a typo in here. its meant to be class Image.

Comment: this.svg.onload = function() {
    this._W = jQuery(".Image").width();
    this._H = jQuery(".Image").height();
    this._best();
   }.bind(this);                                                                                is still showing different width and height for 1st load. second load is correct